# GCP/AWS instances not working with OpenCV imshow

Tags: python, linux, opencv, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform

When I tried to run script on AWS/GCP instance (VM) for OpenCV, the command `cv2.imshow` is not working. This is the error:

> Cannot connect to X server

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('022444057.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `imshow` function is used to display an image on your local machine when you're running the Python script locally. It will open a new window.

It's not possible for a script running on AWS or GCP to "display" an image: it's a server, so there's no display ("Cannot connect to X server") and it doesn't have the ability to show a window on your local machine.

Comment: Hi Dustin, is there any other way to do the same thing ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to train the model online and want see the results using OpenCV real time.

Comment: @milestonezero did you figure out how to do it?